# After moving my files to a new account my PHP Sessions work intermittently in FireFox - IE is fine

Tags: php, shared-hosting

Everything seemed to be working fine, in both IE and FireFox, until I tried to save a few (too few) bucks when my hosting provider hostmonster.com reduced its price. So I had to move all my files from my old account to my new one.

Now in FireFox some of my file $_Sessions are not working and I do not have any idea why.

I have stripped the code down to just opening the database and opening the Session and doing a var_dump($_SESSION); and all I get back is an empty array.

To complicate the problem if after getting this empty array I go to another page without relogging in the $_Sessions work fine. Then if I go back to the page that did not work it still does not work and I can keep doing this getting the same results.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

I am not sure if it is resolved or not but I cleared the history and It seems to work so far. Could this be the whole problem?

Comment: Is your session id being passed around as a $_GET or is it done in a cookie? Also, is there only one page that's acting up? Maybe narrow down where things are failing so we can get a better idea of what's happening.

Comment: It has been more than one page and I am using session_set_save_handler I do not see the #_SESSION variables in the address bar so I do not believe I am useing $_GET.

Answer (score 1):

This problem with sessions comes again and again. I think it was last month I help solve a simular problem. In most cases the cookie required for the session is unable to be stored inside the browser. So in otherwords, are cookies disabled in the browser that disallows sessions. So if it is mozilla firefox that sessions are not working, check that cookies are enabled. Cookies are all enabled then try using the session id in the url.

i hope it would help

Comment: If that is the problem why can I go back and forth to files that do work? But it will not hurt to check.